# Vundle won't install plugins due to an error about AppData/Local/Temp

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, plugin-vundle

I am on Windows 10. I just installed **Vundle** and now I am trying to run the `PluginInstall` command. However, I am getting errors saying it can't open a file in `AppData/Local/Temp`. This does occur on all plugins (at least it seems so).

I am using gvim, which I ran as an admin to make sure it wasn't permissions related. I have tried restarting my machine, as I was doing updates anyway.

Why am I having this issue? Please advise.

P.S. I have looked in AppData, the file it is looking for doesn't exist.

---

[[image: screensnippet of gvim and error[1]]

As the comments suggested, I tried set shell=git and the errors changed to:

[image: Error processing - screensnippet]

I will try out the links.

Comment: Not sure if it'll fix the problem, but I highly recommend vim-plug, https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `git` installed? Vundle uses it to process the installations and it is not by default on Windows.